# How to change the palette-legend in seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've just learned that I can change axis-label font-size using `sns.set_context`. Is there an analogous way to change the content and size of the text in the 'palette-legend' on the right?

[image]

I'd like to enlarge the text and relabel the '0' and '1', which were used for matrix manipulation, back to descriptive text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_title()` and `set_text()` to set the names of the legend title & labels. Similarly, use `plt.setp()` to change the font to the size you need it to be... an example is shown below.

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g=sns.pairplot(penguins, hue="species")

g._legend.set_title("New Title") ## Change text of Title
new_labels = ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3']
for t, l in zip(g._legend.texts, new_labels):
    t.set_text(l)  ## Change text of labels
    
plt.setp(g._legend.get_title(), fontsize=30) ## Set the Title font to 30
plt.setp(g._legend.get_texts(), fontsize=20) ## Set the label font to 20

plt.show()
```

[image]